# State machine - how to handle outside environment values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a state machine implementation in Unity that I'm working on (c#), the plan being that it will be mostly used for AI related things.

I'm not sure how I should deal with various "inputs" / how it should interact with knowledge from the outside environment. Two approaches I've considered and tried so far:

1, I have a dedicated "Query" class that holds various bools. At the end of the Tick() method in each state I make some checks like

```cs
if (queries.JumpUp) { SetState(JumpState); }
```

that take care of switching states. To change states, I simply set the bool to true.
This seems to work fine, creates a very loose relationship between the "query" and the resulting behaviour, and lets me place pretty much all the transition logic in a dedicated method (my base Tick() method calls an CheckForTransitions() method at its end, and it's this method that I override and put all the transition logic in).
It works fine so far, but I'm a bit worried that this type of logic might be almost a bit too loose.

2, Create virtual methods for all possible "events" I would like to be handled.

```cs
public override void TryJump() { SetState(JumpState); }
```

To change states, I explicitly call the method above (or some wrapper around it, implemented inside the StateMachine).

This also seems to work fine. Some slight negatives I can see compared to 1,:
I can no longer rely on the fact that at most one transition will be done per frame, and I also can't rely on the fact that this transition will happen at the end of the frame.
I don't have a single nice place in the code where I can check exactly what sort transitions can happen and what their conditions are.
I will have to have tons of virtual methods for each state, for each "TryJump" method. This might be premature optimization (with 1, I only override "CheckForTransitions()").

Despite that, something just feels a bit off about the method in 1, - using booleans like that just seems a bit weird.

Comment: It's an interesting question but might be better suited for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I agree, better question for SE. Typically changes of state are a response to an action, not triggered by evaluating a Boolean.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/IanMercer/Abodit.StateMachine for an example of how I handled this issue.

Comment: `public override void TryJump() SetState(JumpState)` isn't valid C#. What did you intend by it?

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a state machine implementation in Unity that I'm working on (c#), the plan being that it will be mostly used for AI related things.

> I'm not sure how I should deal with various "inputs" / how it should interact with knowledge from the outside environment.

State machines are fine for simple A.I behaviour but if you're looking for anything more advanced you might be better off with something like [Utility System / Utility A.I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_system).

It's basically a score based system where A.I evaluates actions it can take based on which has the highest score *(can be configured couple other way as well like first action to score)*. Score can be based on external and internal input like how much ammo or health the A.I has left or is the A.I in middle of something like chasing the player (inertia). Like State machines it can also have divided to multiple levels that influence one another like one for reactive actions and one for goal driven behaviour.

There's pretty good open source asset for this for Unity called Apex Utility A.I but it may be a bit dated. It could however offer a good reference if nothing else.

- [Apex-Game-Tools Github](https://github.com/ApexGameTools/Apex-Game-Tools)
- [Apex Utility A.I - Asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/apex-utility-ai-personal-edition-56306)

[Game AI Pro](http://www.gameaipro.com/) has good [article about utility A.I](http://www.gameaipro.com/GameAIPro/GameAIPro_Chapter09_An_Introduction_to_Utility_Theory.pdf) along with bunch of other materials that you may find interesting.

For sharing data some form of [blackboard system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_system) is could be used.